# Enum value and predicates

Tags: swift, enums, nspredicate

Is there a way to use an enum value in an `NSPredicate` without calling `rawValue`?

For example:

```
enum MyEnum: Int32 {
    case A, B, C
}

var predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "prop_status == %i",
                                         argumentArray: [MyEnum.A])
```

I was thinking about extending `NSPredicate` so that it can handle `MyEnum` but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I dont think there is any way to do this unless you use rawValue. Swift enums when inherited from Int32 does not mean it is Int32 by itself. It just means that raw Int32 values determine the enumerations in enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do would be using CustomStringConvertible, when you conform to this protocol you would need to implement description method that return String type. Then you could use String.init method on it to get the string value.

Some thing like this,

```
enum MyEnum: Int32, CustomStringConvertible {
    case A, B, C

    var description: String {
        return "\(rawValue)"
    }
}

var predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "prop_status == %@",
    argumentArray: [String(MyEnum.A)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way around this would be to create the `NSPredicate` with a block.

```
enum MyEnum: Int32 {
    case A, B, C
}

class MyClass: NSObject {
    var status: MyEnum

    init(status: MyEnum) {
        self.status = status
        super.init()
    }
}

let array = [MyClass(status: .A), MyClass(status: .B), MyClass(status: .C)]
let predicate = NSPredicate { ($0.0 as? MyClass)?.status == .A }
let filteredArray = (array as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

Comment: Thank U, This made my day. I was struck trying hard for past 1-2 hour.

Answer (score 1):

`NSPredicate` is an Objective-C framework, it doesn't understand the concept of enums. Everything that `NSPredicated` gets must be objects. It doesn't actually get a swift array of `Int32`, it gets a `NSArray` instance with a `NSNumber` instance.

Swift can handle array => `NSArray` and `Int` => `NSNumber` conversions behind the scenes but it cannot convert an enum value to its raw value automatically. The compiler just doesn't have enough information to do that.